# Autofit a table to the column width using latex

Tags: tables

I am creating a  9 column document using latex.but it does not fit properly in a document.
How can i autofit the table.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Can you share a small compilable example which demonstrates your problem?